# How to log the class / line number of an event in sails.js with winston

Tags: node.js, sails.js, winston

How can I save the class and line number log entries come from in sails.js? Currently, it shows the log and log level, but not the line from which the log entry came.

E.g. if a `log` statement exists or an exception is thrown in `foo.js` on line `x`, I'd like the logs to have a line like:

> [*timestamp*][foo.js][line x] *details*...

Comment: Can't you just detect it yourself? Just read the log and find the last occurrence (or first) of the log info.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that. But is it possible to log the line number somehow?

Comment: I clarified your title and question. If you have a better example of what your current vs. desired output looks like, please add it :)

Answer (score 0):

When Node.js throws an error it has a `.stack` property containing a stack trace of the error, as text. You could parse it from that. Mind you, seeing the full stack trace message tends to be more useful, rather than assuming the relevant bit will be the first line.